# Val() not getting the complete word J-Query

Tags: jquery

For example i have a word `What world`. I saved this word in this var `$InputValue`. Now the problem is, i am only getting the half word here `+$InputValue+` and that word is `What`. I am not getting the word after the space.

```
var $InputValue = $(this).val(); // What World
alert($InputValue); // What World

$(this).after("<select><option>"+$InputValue+"</option></select>"); //What
```

**jquery:**

```
$("input#"+Get_Current_Select_Field+"Input").each(function()
{
  var $InputValue = $(this).val();
  alert($InputValue);
  $(this).after("<select><option>"+$InputValue+"</option></select>"); //What
});
```

**html:**

```
<select id="ChangeAccount" style="width: 231px">
        <option value="">Select Name</option>
         <option>What World</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle replicating this issue?

Comment: Show us your HTML  and  please show us the change or blur event your binding to.

Comment: Maybe there's CSS that's setting the width of the option.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/X6u7T/ So there must be something else going on.

Comment: what kind of element is $(this) referring to?

Comment: Also work fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/s4KW2/

Comment: i update the answer. i don't know why i am getting the half word. above is all what i am doing

Comment: @user3400389 Can you post a reproducible example at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Jason P http://jsfiddle.net/2A4ud/4/ heres the jsfiddle

Comment: why negative points :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing quotes in your attribute:

http://jsfiddle.net/GX3HG/

```
"value=" + $InputValue + " />"
```

becomes:

```
value=What world />
```

and the value of the `value` attribute is simply `What`.

You need quotes:

```
value='" + $InputValue + "' />
```

so it becomes:

```
value="What world" />
```